# org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond in android

Tags: android, androidhttpclient, android-webservice

Recently move all data to new server, after am got this exception `org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond` in all `JSON` links but its working perfectly in browsers.In old server its was worked well.am not able to solve this.can any one know please help me to solve this issue.

**Coding**

```
HttpClient client;
HttpResponse response;
HttpPost post;
InputStream in;
StringEntity se;
int resp_code;

client = new DefaultHttpClient();
post = new HttpPost(getString(R.string.base_url)+ "getCityList");
response = client.execute(post);
resp_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
String a = json_res_class.convertStreamToString(in);
```

**Log Cat Error**

```
09-10 11:55:22.369: W/System.err(2214): org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
09-10 11:55:22.369: W/System.err(2214):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:85)
09-10 11:55:22.381: W/System.err(2214):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
09-10 11:55:22.381: W/System.err(2214):     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
09-10 11:55:22.381: W/System.err(2214):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
09-10 11:55:22.405: W/System.err(2214):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
09-10 11:55:22.405: W/System.err(2214):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
09-10 11:55:22.409: W/System.err(2214):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
09-10 11:55:22.409: W/System.err(2214):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
09-10 11:55:22.413: W/System.err(2214):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
09-10 11:55:22.413: W/System.err(2214):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-10 11:55:22.421: W/System.err(2214):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution for this?

Comment: @Jay No.but this error is not come all the time.Our server side guys said the problem due rooting two path(but i dint know whats exact problem in server). Now our server side guys solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpClient.getParams(), false);
```